# ssh login with a tunnel through intermediate server in a single command?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

Is there a way in a single SSH command to login via SSH to a remote server passing through an intermediate server?  In essence, I need to create a tunnel to my "bridge server" and via the tunnel to login to the remote server.

For example, I'm trying to compress the following into a single ssh command:

1. ssh -N -L 2222:remoteserver.com:22 bridge_userid@bridgemachine.com
2. ssh -p 2222 remote_userid@localhost

This currently works, but I would rather be able to squeeze everything into a single command such that if I exit my ssh shell, my tunnel closes at the same time.

I have tried the following in my config but to no avail:

```
Host axp
  User          remote_userid
  HostName      remoteserver.com
  IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.eric
  ProxyCommand  ssh -W %h:%p  bridge_userid@bridgemachine.com
```

As per @jasonwryan comments and [the transparent-mulithop link](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html), I'm able to get the following command working:

```
ssh -A -t bridge_userid@bridgemachine.com ssh -A remote_userid@remoteserver.com
```

but now I would like to package that up neatly into my .ssh/config file, and not quite sure what I need to use as my ProxyCommand.  I've seen a couple of links online as well as @boomshadow's answer that requires `nc`, but unfortunately the AIX server I'm using as my bridge machine does not have netcat installed on it.

Comment: `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bridge`...

Comment: @jasonwryan I think I might have something wrong in my config as it is not working.  I've got the following in my .ssh/config for my remoteserver:   ProxyCommand  ssh -W %h:%p  bridge_userid@bridgemachine.com.

Comment: Edit that into your question: it will get lost in the comments. You need to declare the host, `Host Remote`... See http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html

Comment: Can't you just log into the bridge server and ssh to your target server from there?

Comment: @danielkullmann Sure I can.  I'm just trying to avoid doing that, and I would rather keep my ssh key on my local machine instead of having to put it on the bridge server as well.

Comment: @jasonwryan I have updated my question to include my config snippet.

Comment: This answer also explains how to set the `~.ssh/config` file for this task. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437909/276470

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ProxyCommand is what you need. At my company, all the DevOps techs have to use a "jumpstation" in order to access the rest of the VPC's. The jumpstation is VPN access-controlled.

We've got our SSH config setup to automatically go through the jumpstation automatically.

Here is an edited version of my .ssh/config file:

```
Host *.internal.company.com
User jacob
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ProxyCommand ssh -q -A jacob@company-internal-jumphost  nc -q0 %h %p
```

Every time I do an 'ssh' to a server on that 'internal' subdomain, it will automatically jump through the jumpstation first.

***Edit***:
Here is the **entire** section of the .ssh/config for the 'Internal' VPC for us to log into it:

```
# Internal VPC
Host company-internal-jumphost
   Hostname 10.210.x.x  #(edited out IP for security)
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host 10.210.*
   User ubuntu
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company-id_rsa
   ProxyCommand ssh -q -A jacob@company-internal-jumphost  nc -q0 %h %p
Host *.internal.company.com
   User jacob
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ProxyCommand ssh -q -A jacob@company-internal-jumphost  nc -q0 %h %p
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I don't have `netcat` (ie: nc) available on the server.  (It's an AIX server)

Comment: There is a more elegant sollution based on ProxyCommand and the -W option which allows you to do things like `ssh user@hostA/hostB/hostC` to connect to hostC through 2 intermediates, see: http://dmitry.khlebnikov.net/2015/08/transparent-ssh-host-jumping-advanced.html

Comment: Will this work if you have a different username on the intermediary hosts?  Can you use `ssh user@hostA/otheruser@hostB/someone@hostC`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti, yes you can. In my 2nd code block, I've got user 'ubuntu' specified for the 10.210.* hosts. Also, you can change your user on the intermediary host (jump host) using the ProxyCommand. See how I've got "jacob@company....". You can also specify a different user there as well.

Comment: Why not use `ssh -W` in the `ProxyCommand`, provided the SSH version isn't _too_ old (5.4)? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

Answer (score 6):

If OpenSSH 7.3 or later is used then you can use `ProxyJump` like this:

```
$ ssh -o ProxyJump=user1@gateway user2@remote
```

If either user is omitted then the local user is implied.

---

A variation on the indirect login theme is indirect file transfer. You can use `scp` and `rsync` with indirect `ssh` to copy files through the intermediate server.

To copy through the gateway using `scp`:

```
$ scp -oProxyJump=root@gateway myfile user@remote:path
```

If `user` is omitted, the local user is used.

The `ProxyJump` was introduced in OpenSSH 7.3. An alternative is to use `ProxyCommand`:

```
$ scp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p root@gateway" myfile user@remote:path
```

To copy through the gateway using `rsync`:

```
$ rsync -av -e 'ssh -o "ProxyJump root@gateway"' myfile user@remote@path
```

Or

```
$ rsync -av -e 'ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -A root@gateway -W %h:%p"' myfile user@remote@path
```

I paraphrase other answers (on *super**user***) that cover [indirect `scp`](https://superuser.com/a/276549) and [indirect `rsync`](https://superuser.com/a/1115998) in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need an SSH connection via another machine, there's no need to either create a tunnel or edit .ssh/config.

The easiest command I could find is using "jump host" ssh argument

```
ssh -J bridge_userid@bridgemachine.com remote_userid@remoteserver.com
```

Note: this feature is supported starting with OpenSSH 7.3, released on 2016-08-01

http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3