# Correct ssh config file settings to tunnel to a 3rd machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, ssh-config

I'm trying to tunnel to a server via a bridge server. So far, I've been able to get it working from the command shell properly using the following command:

```bash
ssh -A -t bridge_userid@bridgemachine.com ssh -A remote_userid@remoteserver.com
```

But I've been trying to wrap this into my `~/.ssh/config` file and I have troubles. I've tried:

```sshconfig
Host axp
  User          remote_userid
  HostName      remoteserver.com
  IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.eric
  ProxyCommand ssh -A -t bridge_userid@bridge_userid.com ssh -A remote_userid@%h
```

But when I do, I get the following error message from `remoteserver.com` and I'm not sure what is causing it:

> ksh: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8^M:  not found

I know that when I log into `remoteserver.com` , my shell is `/usr/bin/ksh`.

I've tried to add path arguments to the ssh commands in the config file, but it made no difference.

Any ideas what it can be?

Comment: That's just not how `ProxyCommand` is meant to be used. Typically it is used with netcat where ssh is piping its output through it and netcat is acting as the tunnel to the _remoteserver_ SSH port. You need a ProxyCommand something like `ssh -W %h:%p bridge_userid@bridgemachine.com` if you want to use that feature.

Comment: Unfortunately my bridge server does not have netcat installed on it, so I'm trying to get this to work some other way.  I figured if it could work from the command line, there should be a way to put the info in a config file.

Comment: In your command line usage that works you are giving `ssh -A remote_userid@remoteserver.com` as a command to run on the bridge machine, config does not give you a way of supplying default commands. What you attempt to do `works` in itself but then ssh tries to use your `ProxyCommand` as a tunnel and starts firing SSH protocol down it where there is a shell waiting at the other end rather than an sshd listening for SSH protocol.

Comment: @dansut worked great.  Thx!

Answer (score 58):

[Jakuje's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234993/63222) is right, but since OpenSSH `7.3`, you can now use `-J` `ProxyJump` which is easier. See my notes:

## OpenSSH `7.3` or above

Use `ProxyJump`. As explained in the manual:

> -J [user@]host[:port]
>    Connect to the target host by first making an ssh connection to the jump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there. Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters. This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.

### ProxyJump `~/.ssh/config` example

`~/.ssh/config`

```sshconfig
Host server1
  Hostname server1.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server2_behind_server1
  Hostname server2.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyJump server1
```

Connect with

```bash
ssh server2_behind_server1 -v
```

Add `-v` for verbose output

### ProxyJump `-J` Command line example

`~/.ssh/config`

```sshconfig
Host server1
  Hostname server1.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server2
  Hostname server2.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Connect with

```bash
ssh server2 -J server1 -v
```

Or use `-o`

```bash
ssh server2 -o 'ProxyJump server1' -v
```

## OpenSSH `5.4` or above

Use `ProxyCommand` with `-W`

`~/.ssh/config`

```sshconfig
Host server1
  Hostname server1.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server2
  Hostname server2.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand ssh server1 -W %h:%p
```

Connect with

```bash
ssh server2 -v
```

Or use `-o`

```bash
ssh server2 -o 'ProxyCommand ssh server1 -W %h:%p' -v
```

### OpenSSH bellow `5.4`

`~/.ssh/config`

```sshconfig
Host server1
  Hostname server1.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server2
  Hostname server2.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand ssh server1 nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Connect with:

```bash
ssh server2 -v
```

Or use `-o`

```bash
ssh server2 -o 'ProxyCommand ssh server1 nc %h %p 2> /dev/null' -v
```

## Sources

`-J` added in [OpenSSH 7.3](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3)

> - ssh(1): Add a ProxyJump option and corresponding -J command-line
>     flag to allow simplified indirection through a one or more SSH
>     bastions or "jump hosts".

`-W` added in [OpenSSH 5.4](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4)

> - Added a 'netcat mode' to ssh(1): "ssh -W host:port ..." This connects
>     stdio on the client to a single port forward on the server. This
>     allows, for example, using ssh as a ProxyCommand to route connections
>     via intermediate servers. bz#1618

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `netcat` on your bridge. As DanSut proposed in the comments you can use the `ssh -W` command line option instead, this configuration should work for you:

```sshconfig
Host axp
  User          remote_userid
  HostName      remoteserver.com
  IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.eric
  ProxyCommand ssh -AW %h:%p bridge_userid@bridge_userid.com
```

Comment: It worked.  Thanks.  Not sure why, but am sure I had tried it once already in failure, but I tried again with success.  Thanks.