# Connecting to my lab worksation via SSH -X so that I can run the python scripts and see the graphical results

Tags: ssh

I used to connect to my lab **workstation A** using my **workstation B** using `ssh -X me@A`

But recently they added an intermediate **headless server C** and hence I need to do this `ssh -X me@C` and then `ssh -X me@A` . While I can connect via ssh from B to C to A, the graphics the functionality is missing.

It is giving me this run time error:

**[Open3D ERROR] GLFW Error: X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing.**

I believe that DISPLAY environment variable is missing on the server C . How can resolve this error and be able to see the graphical results on my workstation B? Please enlighten me to search in the right direction !

Comment: What happens if you use `ProxyJump` (like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437909/70524) to connect to A via C?

Comment: The answer to your problem is here, https://serverfault.com/a/53082/193541. What you are doing wrong is sending your graphical data to the intermediate server for display, **not** to your A machine. The answer linked to above will allow you to correct this, to forward your graphical data from C thru B to A for display on A. Cheers.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I am getting this error:  **channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer**

Comment: @muru  I am getting this error: **channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Name or service not known
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host**

Comment: @amitoz what was the configuration you used?

Comment: It says: *Temporary failure in name resolution*. It means server B does not know the name you are using for C. Try using for C its LAN IP address.