# How to copy remote NAS file behind a router

Tags: files, scp

#### BACKGROUND

A UNIX NAS operates behind a Unix Router.  The router's SSH port is open to the WAN, however the SSH port of the NAS is LAN accessible only.  One is able to SSH to the router from any WAN connections (i.e. Starbucks) from Unix command line (Bash).

To access the NAS, one must provide login through the router and then login to the NAS.

#### QUESTION

Is it possible to remotely retrieve (from NAS side of router) files from the NAS via:

- command-line (scp, rsync, etc)?
- application (FileZilla)?

Examples are preferred & appreciated.

Comment: After router authentication, one is 'inside' the router with command line access.  Thanks for the questions as it serves to 'sharpen' the original post

Comment: Ok please add that to your question so it's clear to everyone who reads it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh login with a tunnel through intermediate server in a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215986/100397)