# Connect to ssh from another ssh via script

Tags: ssh

I have a script to connect to AWS via ssh. the content of the script is very simple:

```
#! /bin/bash
ssh -i private_key.pem ec2-user@ec2-11-11-111-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I run this script from the terminal:

```
./connect
```

And so I connect to this one AWS.

What I want to do is to connect from one AWS to second.
Basically, after I run the script I can type

```
ssh second_aws
```

But I want to do it in one script such that I will run the script and my terminal will connect to second AWS, something like:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 ssh -i private_key.pem ec2-user@ec2-11-11-111-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
 ssh second_aws
```

But if I will run this it moves to one AWS and doesn't connect to second AWS.

How can I use the script, run it from the terminal and my terminal will connect to the second computer?

Comment: Not tried with AWS, but with some hosts here chaining 2 ssh commands together works if "-A -t" is added: ssh -A -t user@firsthost ssh user@secondhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh login with a tunnel through intermediate server in a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215986/ssh-login-with-a-tunnel-through-intermediate-server-in-a-single-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider just telling the first host to execute the `ssh` command, instead of giving you a shell:

```
ssh -t -i private_key.pem ec2-user@ec2-11-11-111-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com ssh -t second_aws
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing does not open the second connexion from your AWS instance. It opens the connexion from the where the script is launched.

You should look for the `ProxyJump` option. It'll allow you to chain several SSH connexions.

Here's an extract from the `man` page :

```
 ProxyJump
         Specifies one or more jump proxies as either [user@]host[:port] or an ssh URI.  Multiple proxies may be separated by comma characters and will be visited sequentially.  Setting this option will cause ssh(1) to connect
         to the target host by first making a ssh(1) connection to the specified ProxyJump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate target from there.

         Note that this option will compete with the ProxyCommand option - whichever is specified first will prevent later instances of the other from taking effect.

         Note also that the configuration for the destination host (either supplied via the command-line or the configuration file) is not generally applied to jump hosts.  ~/.ssh/config should be used if specific configuration
         is required for jump hosts.
```

Comment: I want to use .pem file only for the first connection. And I don't see how to do it with ProxyJump.